# iOS：How to let a `uiview` support portrait and landscape orientation？

Tags: ios, uiview, landscape-portrait

I have a `photoBroser` which is inherited `uiview`:

```
@interface SDPhotoBrowser : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

But now I have a requirement to let the `photoBroser` support `iphone`
portrait and landscape orientation, and how to do this ?

[image: my photobroser]

EDIT:In my application, my app only support `portrait` orientation， only in my `photoBrowser` which is `uiview`, I want to support `portrait and landscape` orientation.

EDIT:I apply `J.Hunter`'s answer, and his answer is very good, in the actually coding, I suggest a function to change `portrait and landscape orientation`.When I dismiss my `photoBrowser`, there comes an issue, after my `photoBrowser` dismiss, the device is `landscape orientation` yet, and so I use the code below to let my device `portrait orientation`, and then my `photoBrowser` dismiss, so there show reasonably.

```
//（force landscape：[self interfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];）
//（force Portrait：[self interfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];）
+ (void)interfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
        SEL selector  = NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:");
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[UIDevice instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
        [invocation setSelector:selector];
        [invocation setTarget:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
        int val = orientation;
        // from 2
        [invocation setArgument:&val atIndex:2];
        [invocation invoke];
    }
}
```

This function maybe helpful for perfect `support portrait and landscape orientation` in code.

Comment: Is your app support both portrait and landscape orientation？Or only support portrait orientation?

Comment: In Xcode in the root of project you have General>Deployment Info>Device Orientation.....and then check what orientation you want.

Comment: @J.Hunter I apologize for my partial question, and I have complete some description to my question.

Comment: @Milos Mandic I know your meaning, but I just want to know how to make a`uiview` support portrait and landscape orientation, and you can see my `EDIT` in my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know your app only support portrait orientation. It will take your two step to support portrait and landscape orientation in special view controller.
I suppose you using Objective-C
1. add a property in `AppDelegate.h` named `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldRotation;`
2. In 'AppDelegate.m', implement orientation method of `UIApplicationDelegate` - `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window`, just like

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (self.shouldRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Now you can support landscape orientation in any UIViewController you want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // enable landscape orientation
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.shouldRoration = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // disable landscape orientation
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.shouldRoration = NO;
}
```

May it be helpful.
PS, there is another way to solve it:

1. You app support all orientation
2. All of your UIViewController override `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations`, return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` or `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`

Comment: Your answer is very corret for me.Thank you.